# How is ADMM Separable?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, admm

I'm learning about ADMM by reading Boyd's paper [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf).

The paper says that ADMM is an improvement over the Method of Multipliers because the latter requires the minimization of the augmented Lagrangian:

$L_\rho(x,y) = f(x) + y^T (Ax − b)+(\rho/2)\lVert Ax − b\rVert^2_2$

which we cannot minimize in parallel because the added quadratic penalty term makes the function non-separable.

However, the paper says that ADMM requires minimization of the augmented Lagrangian functions:

$x^{k+1} = \underset{x}{\operatorname{argmin}} L_{\rho}(x,z^k,y^k)$

$z^{k+1} = \underset{z}{\operatorname{argmin}} L_{\rho}(x^{k+1},z^k,y^k)$

where the augmented Lagrangian is defined as

$L_{\rho}(x,z,y) = f(x) + g(z) + y^T(Ax + Bz − c)+(\rho/2)\lVert Ax + Bz − c\rVert^2_2$

The paper says that ADMM is an improvement because it has decomposability unlike the Method of Multipliers. However, shouldn't the augmented Lagrangian for ADMM also be non-separable because it also contains a quadratic penalty term $(\rho/2)\lVert Ax + Bz − c\rVert^2_2$ at the end? What allows it to be more decomposable?

Comment: x is fixed while minimizing with respect to z and vice versa.

Comment: @Brian Yes, but even if we treat z as a constant while minimizing the function for x, there is still an x in the quadratic term. So how can we separate the function into multiple terms and minimize x in parallel?

Comment: We've decomposed the original primal variable (x,z) into x and z.  You can extend this further to an N-way decomposition, but additional assumptions are needed to ensure convergence.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Does that mean in an N-way decomposition, you would need to alternate updates for N variables? But I don't think you can do the updates in parallel? For example, for (x,z), you cannot update x and z at the same time.

Comment: Chapter 7 of the reference by Boyd et al.  that you linked to in your question talks about this.